# send html mail with php

Tags: php, html, email

I Have php code to send mail like this :

```
    <?php
    $to='123.123@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'testing';
    //create a boundary string. It must be unique
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: 123@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: 123@gmail.com";
    //add boundary string and mime type specification
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
    //define the body of the message.
    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
    ?>
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"
    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    <?php
//html content
    include ("http://10.*.*.*/maps/tes.php");
    ?>

    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>
    #Content-Type: application/html; name="racing_mkios_data_wok_sbt_201403.html"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment

    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

    <?php
    //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
    $message = ob_get_clean();
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
    ?>
```

it send me html code not the content. what wrong wit my code? 
I had been googling for One Hour still can't find the answer 
............................................................

Comment: make sure sendmail works in your server. if not use SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your headers content type to text/html.
Switch this line:

```
 $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

to:

```
 $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

Comment: The PHP mail function simply needs to have its content type set to text/html for it to be able to send HTML mails. More can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php